# Line integral over a intersection of a cylinder and a plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Here is the question I'm trying to answer:

> Compute $$\int_C(y−z)\, dx+(z−x)\, dy+(x−y)\, dz$$ where $C$ is the
>   intersection of the cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and the plane $x−z = 1$.

I don't understand how to start this question and would like some help. I normally know how to evaluate the line integrals but I don't know how to evaluate this one I've never seen one of this type before.

Please give any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of steps:

1. Draw a picture of the cylinder and the plane, and of the intersection.
2. What shape is the intersection? Try to parametrize it. (*Hint:* notice that its shadow on the $x$-$y$ plane is a circle, so once you parametrize this you only need to parametrize the $z$ coordinate. This can be deduced from the system of equations you provide.)
3. Once parametrized, evaluate the line integral as usual.

Comment: I don't know how to draw it. I just cannot visualize what it should look like. I think it may be an ellipse but I don't know what to do with the second step.

Comment: A helpful way to draw such things is to hold one variable constant, then think about what happens when that variable changes. For example, when $z = 0$, the first equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ describes a circle on the xy-plane. What happens as $z$ changes? For the second, hold $y$ constant (which doesn't change the equation), then sketch the corresponding line on the $zx$-plane. Now, what happens here as $y$ changes? It is indeed an ellipse. You only need to draw a rough picture here to guide your parametrization of the intersection. If you prefer to do this completely algebraically...

Comment: you can observe that the intersection defines a function on the unit circle in the xy-plane, and the second equation tells you the height of that function. But I think it is a good idea to learn how to sketch what is going on here, since the individual steps for deriving the parametrization may change from problem to problem, but the overall idea will be the same (look at the shadow, parametrize it, and determine the height at time t using the given formula.)

Comment: okay how would I parametrize this?

Comment: @Smithy One parametrizes a circle using sine (y coordinate) and cosine (x coordinate). Then, given a point on your ellipse, if the x-y coordinates are fixed the z coordinate must satisfy the relationship $x - z = 1$, so we know that $z = x - 1$.